# Primary key in MySQL: INT(n) or UUID as varchar(36)

Tags: mysql, primary-key

Does it make sense to use UUID as primary key in MySQL?

What would be pros and cons of using UUID instead of regular INT, beside trouble of hand querying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The major downside of UUIDs is that you have to create them beforehand if you want to refer back to the record for further usage afterwards (ie: adding child records in dependent foreign keyed tables):

```
INSERT INTO table (uuidfield, someotherfield) VALUES (uuid(), 'test'));
```

will not let you see what the new UUID value is, and since you're not using a regular auto_incremented primary key, you can't use `last_insert_id()` to retrieve it. You'd have to do it in a two-step process:

```
SELECT @newuid := uuid();
INSERT INTO table (uuidfield, someotherfield) VALUES (@newuid, 'test');
INSERT INTO childtable ..... VALUES (@newuid, ....);
```

Comment: That's a good point, didn't think about this one. Even though it's relevant if we're talking about simultaneously adding something to two or more tables, not to a single table.

Comment: This is true, but the main benefit to using UUIDs is that you can create them anywhere. If you need a UUID when you insert the record, just generate it client-side, and include it explicitly in your `INSERT` statement rather than letting the database generate it.

Answer (score 9):

From my point of view, using UUID as primary key in MySQL is bad idea, if we speak about large databases (and large amount of inserts).

MySQL always creates Primary Keys as clustered, and there is no option to switch it off.

Taking this in to consideration, when you insert large amounts of records with non-sequential identifiers (UUIDs), database gets fragmented, and each new insert would take more time.

**Advice:** Use PostgreSQL / MS-SQL / Oracle with GUIDs. For MySQL use ints (bigints).

Answer (score 5):

The PRO I can think of is that your ID will be unique, not only in your table but on every other table of your database. Furthermore, it should be unique among any table from any database in the world.

If your table semantic needs that feature, then use a UUID. Otherwise, just use a plain INT ID (faster, easier to handler, smaller).

Answer (score 4):

The cons of UUID is that it's bulkier and hence a bit slower to search.  It's hard to type in a long hex string for every ad hoc query.  It solves a need that you might not have, i.e. multi-server uniqueness.

By the way, `INT(n)` is always a 32-bit integer in MySQL, the `(n)` argument has nothing to do with size or range of allowed values.  It's only a display width hint.

If you need an integer with a range of values greater than what 32-bit provides, use `BIGINT`.